# Django - how to call a parent function in a child model

Tags: django, function, model, parent-child

I have a child model with a Foreignkey ("Objective"), that related to a parent model ("Project") in Django. So the "Project" has many "Objectives". My goal is to divide the amount of one particular objective to the total amount of the Project, computed by the function "total_budget". Hence, I am trying to call the function "total_budget" in the "Objective" model. Is it possible? Is that the best way to do it?

Here is my models.py code:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    model_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=True)
    current_savings = models.IntegerField()
    monthly_salary = models.IntegerField()
    monthly_savings = models.IntegerField()
    horizon = models.DateField(default='2025-12-31')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.model_name)
        super(Project, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def total_budget(self):
        #define current date and horizon to compute the number of months until horizon
        curr_date = datetime.date.today()
        horizon = self.horizon
        dates = [curr_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), horizon.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')]
        start, end = [datetime.datetime.strptime(_,'%Y-%m-%d') for _ in dates]
        re_mon = (end. year - start. year) * 12 + (end. month - start. month)

        #budget is equal to the monthly savings times remaining months, plus current savings
        budget = self.monthly_savings*re_mon + self.current_savings

        return budget



    class Objective(models.Model):
        project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='objectives')
        title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=0)
        expiration = models.DateField()
        isexpensed = models.BooleanField()
        investable = models.BooleanField()
    
        class Meta:
            ordering = ('expiration',)
    
        def pct_totalbudget(self):
            project = Project
    
    
    
            return absamount
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: It is not really clear to me what you need here. The sum of the `amount`s of all *related* `Objective`s?

Comment: Exactly, I am trying to get the sum of the amount of all objectives related to a project. So that I can compute the proportion of each objective's amount to the total sum.

Answer (score 1):

You can sum up the `amount`s of all *related* `Objectives` with:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

self.objectives.aggregate(
    total_amount=Sum('amount')
)['total_amount'] or 0
```

where `self` is the `Project` object.